# Unexpected screen overlay blending when rendering CIImage that has been loaded DIRECTLY from a file instead of via a UIImage

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

I'm trying to speed up my image processing code. One factor I was trying was to create a `CIImage` **directly**, like so:

```
CIImage* ciImageStrong;
if (_cachedData)
{
    _cachedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathForResource];
    ciImageStrong = [CIImage imageWithData:_cachedData];
}
else
{
    ciImageStrong = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathForResource]];
}
```

my problem is, that when using it with a standard `@"CISourceOverCompositing"` filter, all images are drawn **ADDITIVELY** instead of **normal alpha blend**.

When I use the following code, it all works fine:

```
UIImage* uiImageStrong;
if (_cachedData)
{
    _cachedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathForResource];
    uiImageStrong = [UIImage imageWithData:_cachedData];
}
else
{
    uiImageStrong = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathForResource];
}
CIImage* ciImageStrong = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:uiImageStrong.CGImage];
```

I've tried loading it with the kCGColorSpaceModelRGB colorspace to no avail.
Questions:

- Does anybody know **why** this is going on?
- Maybe someone knows if there is **something** to be gained by loading a `CIImage` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've leaned enough about `CGImage` to know the first solution wouldn't have speed up the loading of images. `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathForResource]` is very fast and `UIImage.CGImage` has no discernible performance cost whatsoever.